# Nginx, Apache and Plesk

Tags: apache, nginx, reverse-proxy, plesk

I am currently trying to take some load of my Apache web server.
The idea is to let nginx handle the static files.

The procedure is simple nginx pass-> 8080 to Apache.
There is just one problem.

The server has Plesk installed, and Plesk handles the vhosts with the .include files in every vhost folder/config.

Every vhost has an different port and setup in his own .include file, and that makes it impossible to change the Apache port to 8080 on a global level.

Any ideas?

Comment: [Plesk 11 supports nginx out of the box.](http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP11/11.0/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-administrator-guide/index.htm?fileName=70837.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, it's better to use latest plesk 11, because it has native nginx support and it's actually stable now.

Since Plesk 9.5 appears ability to change apache ports through [/usr/local/psa/admin/bin/websrvmng](ftp://download1.swsoft.com/Plesk/Panel9.5/Doc/en-US/plesk-9.5-unix-advanced-administration-guide.pdf) check for --set-http-port and --get-http-port in [this pdf](ftp://download1.swsoft.com/Plesk/Panel9.5/Doc/en-US/plesk-9.5-unix-advanced-administration-guide.pdf)

Since Plesk 10.2 there is ability to change apache port on global level through plesk database http://kb.parallels.com/11232